# magento PHP Fatal error: Class 'Varien_Data_Tree_Node_Collection'

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

after moving my mangento installation fromm mywebsite.com/mangento To mywebsite.com
I get an error message:\

my magneto is displaying "Site Down For Maintenance" with white screen

I get an error in my error_log file

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Varien_Data_Tree_Node_Collection' not found in public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Tree.php on line 51

Comment: I also changed the url in my database core_config_data

Answer (score 0):

Varien_Data_Tree_Node_Collection  make sure this class file collection.php exist is in folder Varien/Data/Tree/Node/Collection.php
Also check its permission.

There is a probability that during upload/Move some files were not uploaded successfully

Comment: if i change the Permission to 0644 Nothing happens

Comment: something went wring during the transfer. i packaged the file in a zip and the unzipped it in the directory and that did it